# Jax ws Ri Implementation

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, wsdl

I have SEI Interface which is returning List

```
    public ArrayList<Passenger> bookTicket(String[] name)
```

But the problem is wsdl takes Array.In JaxB XmlAdapter is there to convert ArrayList to Passenger array.

```
public class ArrayListAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Passenger[], ArrayList<Passenger>>{
public ArrayList<Passenger> unmarshal(Passenger[] passengers) throws Exception {

    ArrayList list=new ArrayList<Passenger>();
    for(Passenger passenger:passengers){
        list.add(passenger);
    }
    return list;
public Passenger[] marshal(ArrayList<Passenger> passengerList) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("---------------222222222222222");
    Passenger []passengers=new Passenger[passengerList.size()];
    int i=0;
    for(Object passenger:passengerList){
        passengers[i++]=(Passenger)passenger;
    }
    return passengers;
}
}
}
```

But it is giving me Class Cast Exception can not be cast to Passenger while returning ArrayList.

By JaxB Class---

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "bookTicketResponse", namespace = "http://irctc.org/reservationsi/wsdl")
```

@XmlAccessorType(AccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "bookTicketResponse", namespace = "http://irctc.org/reservationsi/wsdl")
public class BookTicketResponse {

```
@XmlElement(name = "return", namespace = "http://irctc.org/reservationsi/types")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=ArrayListAdapter.class)
private ArrayList _return;

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     returns ArrayList
 */
public ArrayList get_return() {
    return this._return;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param _return
 *     the value for the _return property
 */
public void set_return(ArrayList _return) {
    this._return = _return;
}
```

}

Please help me why i am getting class Cast exception bcoz JaxB be provide XmlJavaTypeAdapter to convert CollectionType to Array.I used wsgen tool to generate JaxB Classes

Comment: Is your BookTicketResponse class exactly as `wsgen` generated it, or did you modify it?  I find it a little hard to believe that `wsgen` generated a class that uses raw ArrayLists (meaning, `ArrayList` instead of `List<Passenger>`).

Comment: yes wsgen is generating ArrayList<Passenger> .pls help me i am not understanding why casting problem it is showing

Comment: that to it is marshalling exception..............